# Proof that $|f(x)| \leq |f(c)|+V_{a}^{b}(f)$-bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that if $c \in [a, b]$, then for all $x \in [a, b]$ it follows that
$$|f(x)| \leq |f(c)|+V_{a}^{b}(f)$$

From where $V_{a}^{b}(f)$ represents the total variation of $f$ in $[a, b]$. So, take a partition of $[a, b]$ say $P=\{a, c, x, b\}$, note that
$$V_{a}^{b}(f)=\sup_{P} \{V_{P}(f) \} \geq \sum_{k=1}^{4}|f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1})| \geq |f(x)-f(c)| \geq |f(x)|-|f(c)|$$

I think it is the way I am choosing the partition that makes me arrive at the result, but I do not see it clearly, any suggestions?

Comment: That is correct. What are you unsure about?

Comment: A small correction: $\sum_{k=1}^{4}$ should be $\sum_{k=1}^{3}$.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that maybe my choice of partition was not adequate.